# jQuery - set div width to sum of it's children

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following setup:

html:

```
<div id="holder">
  <div>
    <img/>
    <img/>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#holder { width: 800px; }
```

now, i want to make jQuery gallery and will move line of images to the left and right with negative `margin-left` of inner div.

However, I have to tell `<img/>`s to float to left and set inner div's `width` to sum of widths of images.

How can I do this some clean and nice way?

thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var sum=0;
$('#holder img').each( function(){ sum += $(this).width(); });
$('#holder > div').width( sum );

//alert(sum);
```

this should do the trick ..

The float to the images, you can apply it with css

```
#holder img{float:left;}
```

Comment: @Adam, yes i wasn't sure if you wanted that .. but being in the same line in the question i added it as bonus :)

Comment: this save me a lot of problems with translation in my blog!