# Set div width to sum of its children and its children's width to the sum of their children

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a div that expands the entire window (can scroll horizontally) and resize to its children, which all resize to their children.

So: Parent > Expanding Parents > img Children

This is based on post: [jQuery - set div width to sum of it's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335494/jquery-set-div-width-to-sum-of-its-children)

This is to ultimately create a horizontal image layout that will continue horizontally based on posts with an undefined amount of images.

[Please see this link](http://testing.rooraggio.com/jayandrootest/HorzScrolling/). Goal is to have images float left in each parent and each parent float left within main parent.

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table><tr>");
    $(".post").wrap("<td>");
});

$(function(){   
    var sum=0;
    $('.post img').each( function(){ sum += $(this).width(); });
    $('td > div').width( sum );
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrap">    
    <div class="post">
        <img src="../newimages/ford_models_chris1.jpg"/>
        <img src="../newimages/ford_models_chris1.jpg"/>        
    </div>
<div class="post">
    <img src="../newimages/ford_models_chris1.jpg"/>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.post').each(function(){
  var width=0;
  $(this).find('img').each(function(){width+=$(this).width();})
  $(this).width(width+'px');
});
```

make your images float:left to complete this

Answer (score 0):

you can add `overflow:auto` to the parent's css