# Flexible DIV Container (But Not Responsive)

Tags: jquery, html, css, containers

First, let me say I do NOT want a responsive layout.  With that settled...

I have a div container (which we will call ".container") and two elements inside of it (my content, which we will call ".left" and a sidebar which we will call ".right").

I am looking for a way to make the container equal the width of the other two ***including*** the 15px margin on .right.

I do not want to simply set the container to 715px and do not want a CSS3 solution, I want the container to be set to 715px automatically.  I do not know if this is achievable through CSS but I am sure it is through jQuery.  If anybody knows the easiest/cleanest/fastest way to do this it would be appreciated!

```
.container {
}
.left {
width: 500px;
float:left
}
.right {
width: 200px;
margin-left:15px;
float:right
}
```

EDIT:
MY CURRENT MARKUP

```
#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    clear:both;
    padding:35px 0
}

#post_content {
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:660px;
    padding:0 35px 0 0;
    border-right:1px solid #EEE;
    background:#FFF
}
#sidebar {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right!important;
    width:410px;
    overflow:hidden
}


<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="post_content">

<!-- Grab posts -->
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- Breadcrumbs -->
<?php if (function_exists('dimox_breadcrumbs')) dimox_breadcrumbs(); ?>

<!-- Avatar -->
<span class="post_avatar">
    <a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . '/author/' . get_the_author_meta('login'); ?>">
    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '50' ); ?>
    </a>
</span>

<!-- Title -->
<h1 class="post">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</h1>

<!-- Post time, author, category -->
<span class="sub-title-post">By <?php the_author_posts_link( ); ?> <span class="sub-title-divider">|</span> <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <span class="sub-title-divider">|</span> <a href="#commentlist"><?php comments_number( 'No comments', 'One comment', '% comments' ); ?></a>
</span>


<!-- The post -->
<?php the_content(); ?>

<!-- Tags -->
<div class="tag_spacer">

    <h3 class="tags">
    <?php the_tags('Tags ',' / ','<br />'); ?>
    </h3>

    <h3 class="tags">
    <?php $turl = getTinyUrl(get_permalink($post->ID));
echo 'Short URL <a href="'.$turl.'">'.$turl.'</a>' ?>
    </h3>
</div>

<!-- Next/Previous Posts -->
<div class="mp_archive2">
<div id="more_posts">

<div class="oe">
    <?php previous_post_link('%link', '« Previous post', TRUE); ?>
</div>

<div class="re">
    <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post »', TRUE); ?>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<?php comments_template(); ?>

</div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>No matching entries found.</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div>


</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you can do this without resorting to javascript is by floating the container itself, like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WGM4/).

If you're okay using jQuery for it, then you can use [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hFZM6/).

```
$().ready(function(){
   $('.container').width($('.left').outerWidth(true) + $('.right').outerWidth(true)); 
});
```

Make sure you're very specific with your rules here so that `.left` and `.right` only return a single element. You're probably better off switching to IDs instead of class names in this regard.

Comment: What does your HTML code actually look like? Did the jsFiddle link I provided work? If so, you have something else going on in your code that would prevent it from working.

Comment: Thanks!  It was a plugin in WordPress (isn't it always.).

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this with `display: inline-block;` and `overflow: auto;`

```
.container {
overflow: auto;
}
.left {
width: 500px;
display: inline-block;
}
.right {
width: 200px;
margin-left:15px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

What you'll need to watch for is that this will be semi-fluid but will correctly contain the  divs but you'll need to set a width or min-width to prevent the semi-fluid part (it'll wrap if the broswer window is smaller than the content). For the width, like you suggested you can use jQuery.

You'll be able to use a sum of its children such as

```
var sum=0;
$('#container.div').each( function(){ sum += $(this).width(); });
$('#container').width( sum );
```

This is from [jQuery - set div width to sum of it's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335494/jquery-set-div-width-to-sum-of-its-children)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. In this form it calculates the width of all children of `.container`, but you could easily add a selector to `children` to use only `.left` and `.right`:

```
$(".container").width(function() {
   var total = 0;
    $(this).children().each(function() {
       total += $(this).outerWidth(true); 
    });
    return total;
});
```

Here's a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/rmQes/1/). The most useful part of this is the [`outerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) method, which takes a parameter indicating whether or not margin should be included in the returned value.