# Make responsive container snap to elements as it resizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a dynamic width container div that contains constant width items. I'd like to be able to resize the container so that it only ever shows whole items, never cutting the item on the right in pieces.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDxRt/1/)

For example, a user's screen may render showing 5 items:

[image]

If that user were to start shrinking the width of their screen, as soon as the bar is no longer wide enough to hold 5 full items I would like it to shrink down to only showing 4 items.

Bad:

[image]

Good:

[image]

I know this is possible to achieve by using CSS3 media queries, but I'd like to avoid writing a different breakpoint for every single different number of elements. I'd also like to avoid using a javascript `resize` event handler, though I am not sure if this is possible without it.

Comment: I think you're going to need something more complex, perhaps needing JS.  Maybe there is a library out this that supports this.

Comment: @Enzino same issue as Stefan Henze's answer. this causes a big empty space on the right side of the container. i want the container to shrink when it can't fit another element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Pure CSS (some limitations)

This solution is based off a modification to [another solution for a similar problem I gave elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927743/align-width-of-container-div-to-the-sum-of-floating-div/15009298#15009298).

**[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rDxRt/66/)**

It involves a complex relationship of overlapping pseudo-elements to create the borders, which can cause the solution to have certain limitations on what may or may not be able to be done within it (complex backgrounds would be an issue, as well as a necessity for certain positioning aspects). Nevertheless, it functions in the given case.

**A Bit of Explanation**

Essentially, each `.item` element is building its own section of top/bottom borders using both the `:after` and `:before` elements, the former tied to the `.itemContainer`, the latter tied to the `.item` itself (the `:before` is needed to create the last bit of border at the end of the row). Additionally, the `:before` is also creating the "flexible" position of the right border to give it the responsiveness needed when an element shifts out of view. This is why the `:before` must be related to the `.item` itself, and also why each `:after` element's background must be used to "hide" the right border of the preceding `:before` element.

Since we don't know via css the "count" at any given point as to which element is the "last" in the display, all the `:before` elements must be displayed, but we don't want right borders for them all, hence why the `:after` needs to cover them. As an element shifts down to the next line, its `:after` no longer covers the right border of what has now become the last displayed element, revealing that border to be used as the "right" border of the whole group.

**HTML (Matching your original fiddle)**

```
<div class="itemBar">
    <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>     
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
        <div class="item">10</div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS of main items**

```
.itemBar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%; /* some width can be set, does not need to be this */
}

.itemContainer {
    position: relative; /* :after pseudo-elements are positioned off this */
    z-index: 1; /* needed for pseudo-element interaction */
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 68px;
    width: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid black; /* left border is supplied by this */
}

.item {
    width: 60px;
    height: 62px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* NOTE: CANNOT be given positioning  */
}
```

**CSS of Pseudo Elements**

```
.item::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; /* will position off itemContainer */
    z-index: -1; /* push it to the background */
    top: 0; /* set it to top of itemContainer */
    bottom: 0; /* set it to bottom of itemContainer */
    margin-left: -100%; /* shove it past the far left edge of itemContainer */
    /* next, use padding to bring it back to its position at the end
       of the text string of .item */
    padding-left: 100%;
    /* next, add enough padding on the right to compensate for the right
       padding, right margin, and right border of .item */
    padding-right: 3px; 
    /* next, create the top and bottom border of "container", 
       in conjunction with the :before; so this is a pseudo-border for 
       .itemContainer being created by the .item elements */
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background: #fff; /* hide other :before borders */
}

.item:before { /* make right border */
    content: '';
    padding-top: 66px; /* give it .itemContainer height minus border heights */
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -3px; /* .item top margin + border width */
    margin-left: -100%; /* pull the text in .item back into position */
    margin-right: 0;
      /* next, push this behind the background with an even lower z-index
        to hide it if it is not the right most element beign used to 
        form the right border */   
    z-index: -2;
    float: right; /* get the before element to the right */
    position: relative; /* needs to be adjusted in position */
    right: -4px; /* move it same as padding-right of the after element */
    display: block; /* give it a display */
      /*  next, use it to build the fake right border and also the fake
          final top/bottom borders of the of itemContainer */
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: awesome. not entirely sure how this works yet, but it does exactly what i need.

Comment: @jbabey: I added an update with some explanation to help you understand better "how this works."

Answer (score 4):

Remove:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

from .itemBar

and add

```
text-align:justify;
```

to .itemContainer

This way, other items which does not fit there will fall to next line yet the space will be distributed equally.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rDxRt/4/

Comment: Glad it did solve. Can I have my answer as correct marked? :)

Comment: yes of course you can but beware of applying *display:inline; zoom:1;
in order to work properly in ie7.

I would also like to add that once the viewport size exceeds 1336px white space appears in the parent container.

Answer (score 3):

You could have the items in the container float. This way, they will float onto the next line if the container gets to small.

If you are lucky enough and know the height of the items, you can set the container to a fixed height and `overflow: hidden` to make the items that flow to the next line not show up.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AfA8w/2/)

Comment: Yeah, float your elements, fix your container height + overflow hidden.

Comment: This would cause partial elements to not show up, but you would still get the empty space on the right side of the container, right?

Comment: Yes, this solution does not scale the elements to use up the available space. As far as I know, there is no solution that can solve this with just HTML and CSS. You could certainly do it with JavaScript but - given that I don't know your use for this feature - I'd rather opt for a simple solution. It might be optically viable too if the container (`itemContainer` in jsfiddle) does not have a border. Also, if you need to optimize for different devices, choose the width so that elements fill up the space in most resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that's little simpler than ScottS's. It doesn't require any positioning or use of `::before` or `::after`, instead relying on the fact that `::first-line` doesn't stretch past the last visible item.

### The markup

```
<div class="itemContainer">
  <div class="item">1</div><div
  class="item">2</div><div
  class="item">3</div><div
  class="item">4</div><div
  class="item">5</div><div 
  class="item">6</div><div 
  class="item">7</div><div 
  class="item">8</div><div 
  class="item">9</div><div 
  class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Note that this solution is sensitive to inter-element whitespace, so you need to remove newlines/spaces between consecutive `.item`s. I've line-wrapped between the tag name and class above to make it bit more readable.

### The CSS

```
.itemContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 70px; /* .item's offset height + margin */
    /* you can constrain the width of this any way you like */
}
.itemContainer::first-line {
    font-size: 70px; /* needs to be at least as big as .wrap height */
    line-height: 0px; /* fixes oddities in Firefox */
    background: black; /* "border" color */
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-top; /* this minimizes the font-size required  above */
    margin: 10px; /* include desired "border" size of .itemContainer */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 9px white; /* spread = desired margin */
    background: white; /* needs an opaque background */
    /* reset font-size and line-height */
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    /* set your item size and borders however you like */       
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item::first-line {
    font-size: 1rem; /* fix IE precedence */
}
.item + .item {
    margin-left: 0; /* inline-block margins don't collapse */
}
```

### Result

[image: Screenshot from Safari, constrained to only fit 8 of 10 items]

Tested in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11.